# Incompatible `__iadd__` and `__add__` in mypy

Tags: python, mypy, typechecking

I'm writing some code for vectors and matrices where I want to type-check dimensions. I ran into a problem with type-checking `__add__` and `__iadd__`, though. With the simplified example below, `mypy` tells me that  `Signatures of "__iadd__" and "__add__" are incompatible`. They have exactly the same signatures, though, so what am I doing wrong?

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import (
    Generic,
    Literal as L,
    TypeVar, 
    overload,
    assert_type
)


_D1 = TypeVar("_D1")
_D2 = TypeVar("_D2")
_D3 = TypeVar("_D3")

# TypeVarTuple is an experimental feature; this is a work-aroudn
class Shape:
    """Class that works as a tag to indicate that we are specifying a shape."""
class Shape1D(Shape, Generic[_D1]): pass
class Shape2D(Shape, Generic[_D1,_D2]): pass


_Shape = TypeVar("_Shape", bound=Shape)
Scalar = int | float


class Array(Generic[_Shape]):
    @overload # Adding witht the same shape
    def __add__(self: Array[_Shape], other: Array[_Shape]) -> Array[_Shape]:
        return Any # type: ignore
    @overload # Adding with a scalar
    def __add__(self: Array[_Shape], other: Scalar) -> Array[_Shape]:
        return Any # type: ignore
    def __add__(self, other) -> Array:
        return self # Dummy implementation
        
    @overload # Adding witht the same shape
    def __iadd__(self: Array[_Shape], other: Array[_Shape]) -> Array[_Shape]:
        return Any # type: ignore
    @overload # Adding with a scalar
    def __iadd__(self: Array[_Shape], other: Scalar) -> Array[_Shape]:
        return Any # type: ignore
    def __iadd__(self, other) -> Array:
        return self # Dummy implementation
    
    # Adding with a scalar
    def __radd__(self: Array[_Shape], other: Scalar) -> Array[_Shape]:
        return Any # type: ignore


    
A = Array[Shape2D[L[3],L[4]]]()

reveal_type(A + 1.0) ; assert_type(A + 1.0, Array[Shape2D[L[3],L[4]]])
reveal_type(1.0 + A) ; assert_type(1.0 + A, Array[Shape2D[L[3],L[4]]])
reveal_type(A + A)   ; assert_type(A + A,   Array[Shape2D[L[3],L[4]]])

A += 1.0
A += A
```

[Get the code in a playground here.](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=1.0.0&python=3.11&gist=db8381c90caf670070789fdca78fb6ff)

Comment: BTW, the usual convention for unimplemented functions in type stubs is ellipsis `...`: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs.html#stub-file-syntax, https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload

Comment: Yeah, I know, but mypy complained about a missing implementation. I should have used it for the overloads, though; that's true.

Comment: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6225

Comment: The overloads are unnecessary here. Are they required in your original code? Without the overloads mypy is happy

Comment: As a side-note: Since you're relying on 3.11+ anyway (in your use of `typing.assert_type`), you might as well have the return types for all your overloads be (`typing.`)`Self`, so it's both shorter and indicates it should be subclass friendly (if a derived class is involved, it still returns an instance of the derived class, not the parent). I'm not super into `typing`, so it's possible I'm missing a reason *not* to do it, but it seems like what `Self` was made for.

Comment: @Wombatz You are right about the overloads. In the real code, I do need overloads to match dimension constraints, though. With the simplification for SO, the need just disappeared :)

Comment: @ShadowRanger Unfortunately, I need to run on versions going down to 3.9.x, but otherwise I belive you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug they're looking at correcting, [see mypy issue #6225](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6225) (and the older, related, [issue #4985](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4985)). They're trying to protect against some problems that can occur when related operators are overloaded piecemeal on a parent and child class, but oops, it doesn't handle the overloads on a *single* class correctly.

There hasn't been any activity on it in a few years though.

That said, I'm not seeing a need for `@overload` here. Your return type is always the same, not dependent on argument types, so you could just skip the `@overload` variations and use a single coherent type annotation per overload:

```
class Array(Generic[_Shape]):
    def __add__(self: Array[_Shape], other: Array[_Shape] | Scalar) -> Array[_Shape]:
        if not isinstance(other, (Array, int, float)):
            return NotImplemented
        return self
        
    def __iadd__(self: Array[_Shape], other: Array[_Shape] | Scalar) -> Array[_Shape]:
        if not isinstance(other, (Array, int, float)):
            return NotImplemented
        return self
    
    # Adding with a scalar
    def __radd__(self: Array[_Shape], other: Array[_Shape] | Scalar) -> Array[_Shape]:
        if not isinstance(other, (Array, int, float)):
            return NotImplemented
        return self
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. It is good to know that it is a bug and noe me losing my mind. You are right about overloads here--the need went away when I simplilfied for SO--but I do need them in the real code, unfortunately. I found that I could `# type: ignore[misc]` and get away with it, though